# UDP poll() .. issues with POLLOUT

Tags: sockets, udp, polling

I want to code a server with multiple clients with non-blocking UDP sockets and have an issue with turning a client socket into `POLLOUT` mode ...

A client first sends an initial datagram to the server and then only reads from server. Server shall broadcasts datagrams to multiple clients in nonblocking way. So I have an array of

`struct pollfd clients_polled[MAX_NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS + 1]`

Then initialize it this way

```
    /* init client_polled array */
for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS; ++i) {
    clients_polled[i].fd = -1;
    clients_polled[i].events = POLLIN;
    clients_polled[i].revents = 0;
}
```

create listening socket

```
clients_polled[0].fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

then I bind it and call `fcntl`. Then I enter infinite loop in which I first call

```
poll_ret = poll(clients_polled, MAX_NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS, timeout);
```

and if there is `POLLIN` event on listetning socket I read it and add new client and then I send over some stuff to all active clients. So say the first client comes in so after read from it I want to set its event flag from `POLLIN` to `POLLOUT` so that the server can send to it in nonblocking way:

```
clients_polled[1].events = POLLOUT;
clients_polled[1].fd = ??
```

How shall I set `.fd` for it? Shall I assign it to the original `clients_polled[0].fd` or create a new socket like

```
clients_polled[0].fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

Either way I get `.revent` == 1 and nothing is sent over to client

Comment: Is there any reason you want/need to do this with using POLLOUT ? You can just use your one socket. You need to read the message with recvfrom() and store the clients address in a list/array somewhere. When you want to broadcast  something to all your clients, you can loop through that list and call sendto() on your server socket with the client address you stored in your array.

Comment: I do exactly as you wrote and no need to use POLLOUT .. but I thought I need it to improve nonblocking or quasi 'concurrency' ... What if the server is slow with broadcasting while incoming messages keep coming in. If I'm not wrong, those incoming messages will be kept at some OS buffer but what if it overflows?

Comment: That will not be particularly different, as long as your server socket is set to non-blocking. You loop through all your clients and call sendto() until it returns EWOULDBLOCK. If you have not broadcast to all clients, you need to register POLLOUT on your server socket, (and send to the remaining clients when you get a POLLOUT event again)